# Virtual Box Bridged Adapter Redirects to IIS

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding, iis, windows-server-2012, tomato

The setup:

**Router:** TomatoUSB running on a RTN16 router is forwarding several ports to my Server.

**Server:** Windows Server 2012 is host to several VirtualBox Ubuntu VMs.

**One VM**, using NAT works great.

**Another VM**, using Bridged, works great on the internal network.

However, when I try to access the same location from the external network I am presented with the site hosted in IIS instead of my VM.

**Notes:**

Change is not an option, this is about learning, not giving up.

I have considered the possibility that TomatoUSB is the culprit but do not have the technical expertise to prove it so if you can explain how it's at fault, that's a valid answer.

Tomato is configured to forward external port `8081` to internal port `80` on the Bridged IP (`192.168.1.124`), and so what I'm seeing is that port `8081` is giving me port `80` on the Server's IP (`192.168.1.200`).

Per the comments, I attempted a ping to `8.8.8.8` from the bridged VM which returned fine, about 40ms response each time.

Per a request, here's a screenshot of the port forwarding screen on my TomatoUSB.
[image]

The screenshot tells what I have tested to be true.  If I shut off the VM, then try to target port `8081` the site is not found.  No redirection.  So Tomato is pointing at the right IP.  The culprit here is definitely bridged networking, either from the Router's perspective or the VMs.

For further clarification, Tomato clearly shows both the server box and the bridged VM with separate IPs and separate MAC Addresses.  Here is another screenshot.
[image]

I've tested further per IRC.  I disabled the NAT VM's port forwarding and the result was unchanged.  This is further evidence that Tomato is at fault, and not VirtualBox.

Edit:

I ran fiddler from a machine trying to access port `8081` and it shows the response header as a `301` redirect.  This seems to be an after effect.  I'm guessing `8081` is actually what's being sent to the Server IP (`192.168.1.200`) and IIS is redirecting to `80`.

I have pcap files.

Comment: What are the IP addresses involved^ The internal ones.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae edited, added IPs for ya

Comment: From the bridged VM, can you go to the Internet? Can you ping 8.8.8.8, for instance?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes, added results to question

Comment: Have you tried another firmware than Tomato?

Comment: I have not at this point.  But other users with similar issues have different routers and firmware.

Comment: I don't use Tomato, but your rules seem correct on first sight (although too broad). I found via google multiple similar complaints for Tomato, although some have managed to force it to work. As port-forwarding is pure software and nothing to do with hardware, it would maybe be simpler to try with the [latest Asus firmware](http://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN16/#support) as probably having the most efficient usage of the hardware. If you need advanced router firmware, I believe more in DD-WRT.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands the answer to this question is difficult to find: we do not have a culprit yet, let alone a remedy.

Can you run *tcpdump* on both the router and the VM? It would be helpful if you could just confirm that packets are leaving/reaching the router/server (if they do), but you could also check the destination of the packet leaving the Tomato router to confirm it is intended for 192.168.1.124.

The commands to use are simple: on the router,

```
   tcpdump -i any -nn dst 192.168.1.124 and port 80
```

while on the VM

```
   sudo tcpdump -i any -nn port 80
```

In the meantime, from some other pc/shell, try to access port 8081. This way you should get a good idea of the flow of packets. I am not sure the Windows firewall is still off the hook, as a suspect.

If you cannot see anything leaving the router, relax the conditions on the command by issuing instead

```
   tcpdump -i any -nn port 80
```

Comment: sure thing.  I'll run tcpdump tonight.